# Why does $\left (\frac{3+4i}{5} \right)^n$ not converge?

Tags: real-analysis

> Why does $$\left (\frac{3+4i}{5} \right)^n$$ not converge?

I have calculated $\left |\left (\frac{3+4i}{5} \right)^n \right|$ and I got $1$. But in the Solutions they wrote without further comment that this sequence does not converge.

I understood that $|\cdot|\neq0$ is not a necessary condition for convergence because $|(-1)^n|=1$ but does not converge.

But I still don't know how I can prove that the named sequence is not convergent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is as follows: if $|x| = 1$, then
$$
\left|\left(\frac{3 + 4i}{5} \right)x - x\right| = 
|x| \cdot \left|\left(\frac{3 + 4i}{5} \right) - 1\right| = \left|\frac{-2 + 4i}{5}\right| = \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}.
$$
Conclude that $|(\frac{3+4i}{5})^{n+1} - (\frac{3+4i}{5})^n| = \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} > \frac{2}{\sqrt{16}} = \frac 12$ for all $n$, which (by whichever definition of convergence you're comfortable with) is enough to conclude that the sequence $(\frac{3+4i}{5})^n$ fails to converge.

One definition is the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of convergence, which is

> A sequence $a_n$ converges to limit $L$ if, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $n > N$ such that $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $n > N$

I would say that the requirement fails since the sequence fails to be [Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence).

Comment: I see but is there a reason you have considered Looking at $|x^{n+1}-x^n|$ in the first place?

Comment: It's a convenient way of showing that the sequence fails to converge: if the sequence converged to a limit $L$, then $|z^{n+1} - z^n|$ would have to "level off" to $|L-L| = 0$.  I saw that $|z^{n+1} - z^n|$ happens to be (relatively) easy to compute in this case

Comment: However, unless you're used to the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of convergence or something like it, I would say that TheSilverDoe's answer is easier to understand and easier to express in the framework available to you.

Comment: his proof is a clever trick but I accepted your answer because it would be more likely that I could produce something like that on my own. It is also a Concept I can use in other cases

Comment: @New2Math Thank you, and that of course is up to  you.  It is worth knowing that the other answer's trick applies whenever there is a continuous function $f$ for which the sequence $a_n$ satisfies $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$.  In your case, $f(w) = zw$.

Answer (score 3):

Beacuse $$\left (\frac{3+4i}{5} \right)^n  = (\cos \phi +i\sin \phi)^n = \cos (n\phi) + i\sin (n\phi)$$

neither $\cos (n\phi)$ nor $\sin (n\phi)$ converge.

Comment: Although it is true, it is not immediately clear that $\cos(n \phi)$ or $\sin(n \phi)$ fail to converge as $n \to \infty$ (when $\phi$ is not a multiple of $2\pi$).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How does the periodicity of the real trig functions depend on whether the argument is a multiple of $2π$?

Comment: If $\phi$ is a multiple of $2 \pi$, then $\cos(n \phi) = 1$ and $\sin(n \phi) = 0$.  Correspondingly, if $z = 1$, $z^n = 1$ for all $n$, and so the sequence trivially converges.  In any case, the fact that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are periodic functions of a real argument does not in itself allow us to conclude that the sequences $\cos(n \phi)$ and $\sin(n \phi)$ will fail to converge.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh, yes. That is true.

Answer (score 3):

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the sequence $(z^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to a limit $l \in \mathbb{C}$.

Then, write $z^{n-1}  z = z^n$, and let $n$ tend to $+\infty$. You get $lz=l$.

The first possibility is that $l=0$ (in your case, it is impossible because $|z|^n=1$ so $|l|$ has to be $1$).

The second possibility is, dividing by $l$, that $z=1$.

In particular, the only number $z$, with $|z|=1$, such that $(z^n)$ converges, is $z=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your points all lie on the unit circle (since they're just repeated applications of the point $(3/5,4/5)$ on the complex plane).

This thus purely rotates the plane by some positive angle $\phi.$ It should be clear that rotating the plane as many times as you wish does not make the initial vector settle down anywhere, but just rotate every time by the angle $\phi$ forever.